# Search for a Column filter for blanks and loop through workbook

Tags: vba, excel

im a bit of a vba beginner but im trying to write a macro that searches for a column then once its found it filter out blanks then loop it for all the sheets in the workbook

i started with this to find the column

```
SearchCol = "ID"

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = activesheet.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)

With Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="<>"
End With
```

then im trying to combine it with this to loop it through worksheets

```
Dim ws As Object

For Each ws In Worksheets

    With ws.Range("A2")
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
         End With

Next ws
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim SearchCol As String
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    SearchCol = "ID"

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            With ws.Range("A2")
                .AutoFilter field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="<>"
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: right now i want to search for another column leaving that filter on and fill values red that are less than 4 for each cell in that column

Comment: I think you can post it like new question